# How to organize the data in application database?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

My application should contain list of questions + user answers. How should I organize the database:

```
             question1   question2   question2   ...         questionN
user_id_1    yes         no          yes         ...         yes
user_id_2    no          no          yes         ...         no
...
user_id_N    yes         yes         yes         ...         yes
```

Looks like I need to create separate table with questions and assign id to each question. How another table should look like (since number of columns is not fixed)? Or, should I have 2 more tables?

Later on I will also need to:

1. calculate how many users answered 'yes' on *questionN*;
2. how many friends (another table or json data) of *user_id_N* answered 'yes' on *questionN*.

Should I query database each for getting these numbers, or should I have separate database and keep counters there each time user answer (looks possible for item 1 only since friends list can be changed anytime).

Answer (score 2):

A standard way to do this is to store each answer as a separate entity - conceptually the same as you depict, but without the requirement to modify your structure as you add new questions. Here's an example set of model definitions that achieves this:

```
class UserInfo(db.Model):
  # Anything you want to store about the user

class Question(db.Model):
  text = db.TextProperty(required=True)
  # Anything else you want to store about the question

class Answer(db.Model):
  user = db.ReferenceProperty(UserInfo, required=True)
  question = db.ReferenceProperty(Question, required=True)
  answer_text = db.TextProperty(required=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only storing whatever what answered, you should be able to do that with 3 tables.  One for your questions with a one to many to a table with the answers and then another table for the users with a one to many to the answer they provided.

Comment: could you please provide me with example of 'one to many' table? Thanks.

Comment: A one to many table reference is just one where one row in one table can be referenced by many records in the 2nd table via a foreign key (thats the primary key of table one being stored on the 2nd table for every record of that table). 

I think you should look up an intro into database design, read up on 3rd level of normalization.

Comment: could you please provide me with the link to 'intro into database design'?

Comment: Behold! the power of Google!

http://www.datanamic.com/support/lt-dez005-introduction-db-modeling.html

Answer (score 1):

Using a separate table to keep track of the questions themselves might be a good idea. By the way, if you weren't simply leaving out a header for it, your list of user IDs should itself be a specific column in the answer table. It would probably be a good idea to use a separate table to keep track of who is friends with who, though.

Also, while I'm not experienced with accessing a GAE datastore, it's fairly simple to take a count of specific answers in a single column using SQL, at least. `SELECT COUNT(questionN) FROM AnswerTable WHERE questionN='yes'` would be what you'd use as an SQL query.

Note that if you went with Limey's suggestion for the design, the equivalent SQL query would be more like `SELECT COUNT(answer) FROM AnswerTable WHERE questionID='questionN' AND answer='yes'`.